# Simple Rails 3.1 - get error undefined method `hash_for_users_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've just set up rvm with a gemset for rails 3.1 to start building an app in it.

I am trying to just START with a users controller and model. Here is what I have done so far:

```
rails g controller users new


rails generate model user email:string password_digest:string
```

/app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

end
```

/app/views/users/new.html.erb

```
<h1>Signup</h1>

<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
<%= f.label :email %>
<%= f.text_field :email %>
<% end %>
```

config/routes.rb

```
WorkOut::Application.routes.draw do
  get "users/new"
end
```

And That's it. I'm pretty new to rails, and I've tried everything I know, but when I start up rails server, and navigate to http://localhost:3000/users/new I get this error:

```
undefined method `hash_for_users_path' for #<Module:0x00000102ad1058>
Extracted source (around line #3):

1: <h1>Signup</h1>
2: 
3: <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
4: <%= f.label :email %>
5: <%= f.text_field :email %>
6: <% end %>
```

Thanks in advance! I'm sure it's something crazy simple I'm missing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WorkOut::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
end
```

Comment: great. that worked. But in the past I've only had users setup with named routes like - match '/signup', :to => 'users#new' Is this possible with a full resource? new in 3.1?

Comment: you can do it now as well, but you need at least two routes: for new action and create one.

Comment: actually, this seems to be a bug, since it does not work when we have `resource :user` (in singular form).

Comment: @Lailson Bandeira, mmm? you just need to specify a controller name in your case